# Executemany confusion

Tags: python, database, sqlite, executemany

Ok, so I have a function that selects certain rows in a sqlite database based on input from a plugin. I got the plugin to select and fetch rows when just one statement is involved, but since I want to add some flexibility to this, I tried making the function use executemany when encountering lists or tuples. Yet, despite all the things I have fiddled and changed, I a still unable to get this to work, either because the sqlite statement is treating each character in the string as a binding, or because there are too many bindings in the tuple. Here's the code I have so far:

```
    def readoffset(self,offset):
        vartype = type(name)
        print(vartype)
        if vartype == int:
            self.memcursor.execute('''select all id,matbefore,matafter,name,date 
                                   from main as main where id = ?''',[offset])
            undolist = self.memcursor.fetchall()
            print(undolist)
            return(undolist)
        elif vartype == tuple or list:
            print(vartype)
            self.memcursor.executemany('''select all id,matbefore,matafter,name,date 
                                       from main as main where name = (?)''', [offset])
            undolist = self.memcursor.fetchall()
            return(undolist)
```

Comment: Should `vartype=type(name)` be `vartype=type(offset)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/

> Use of this method for an operation
>   which produces one or
>   more result sets constitutes undefined behavior, and
>   the implementation is permitted

So, executemany can be used for INSERT's and UPDATE's but not for SELECT

You can try following code:

```
elif isinstance(offset, (tuple, list)):
    offsets=', '.join(offset)
    self.memcursor.execute('''select all id,matbefore,matafter,name,date 
                                       from main as main where name IN (?)''', [offsets])
```

Comment: @Adam Bernier's variant (with placeholder generation) looks better, because it help prevent SQL injections. You can my code only if all values in `offset` are integers

Comment: something that's rather cool is that `isinstance(offset,(tuple,list))` works too.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you need `executemany` here.
Try something like this instead:

```
self.memcursor.execute('''SELECT id, matbefore, matafter, name, date 
                            FROM main 
                           WHERE name IN (%s)''' % 
                       ','.join('?'*len(offset)), (offset,))
```

Note that the string interpolation is done to place multiple placeholders into the query.